# Use of where-object

Tags: powershell

I would like to use Where-Object to simplify my code and make use of powershell function.

Consider these 2 lists

```
$list = @('A','B','C')
$list2=@{'A'=1;'B'=2;'E'=3}
```

What I would like to do is find out in $list all the items that are keys in $list2. I can do this using the normal trivial way.

```
$r = @()
foreach ($t in $list)
{
  $t
  if ($list2.ContainsKey($t))
  { 
     $r+=$t
     }
}
```

The code above works but when I issue the command below

```
$r = $list | Where-Object $list2.Keys.contains($_)
```

Powershell was not happy and said the method was not supported. I think it should be achievable but I do not know how to issue the proper command. Please help if this is doable as my script seems to be too wordy.

Comment: Hashtables are not ordered. What should the output be? Are you wanting a single output (at least one item from `$list` is a key in the hash), or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap your the conditional that you are evaluating in your `Where-Object` in `{}` to evaluate as a ScriptBlock. Secondly, the `contains()` method will return a boolean for each member of `$list2` so you will want to evaluate that statement for if the returned array contains the value `$True`.

```
$r = $list | Where-Object {($list2.Keys.contains($_)) -contains $True}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `.contains()` method on the `$list2` hashtable itself and avoid getting a value for each key.

```
$r = $list | Where-Object {$list2.contains($_)}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben! Would you mind elaborating a bit more on the 2 ways you suggested? Both ways work as a charm but I am a bit fuzzy on the scriptblock. I would think that both list2.Keys.Contains and $list2.contains would return a logical value of true or false? But in reality only the second one does as the first one would return all the values (true or false) if we do not explicitly filter out the false. Why is that?

Comment: @user1205746 The first one you are checking each individual key when using rather than the whole hashtable. `$list2.Keys` is an array of Keys. `$list2` is the whole hashtable.

Comment: Yes, but the result should still be a true or false, should it not? I apologize if I have missed something as I am very green to powershell

Comment: It is `True/False` but one for each key.